# Is it possible to override a method in a class in a dll file?

Tags: c#, oop

I've included a dll file into my windows form project.
1. Is it possible to override a particular class entirely?
2. Is it possible to add a new method to a particular class in the dll file?
3. Is it possible to override a method in a class in the dll?

Alternatives I would prefer to avoid:
I know I can use extension methods to create static new methods.
I can also inherit from a particular class and then add new methods to the derived class.

What i'm trying to achieve:
i have to create a project now and add it to a larger project as a dll file.
but we've been told that we'll need to add more functionality to the original project next month. I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about this.
the smaller project is based on mvc design.

Comment: well if there is a way to intercept the method call, run an alternate method and return a value to the original calling method, then yes i'd like to know how.

Comment: What class are you trying to override? If it's the class Namespace1.Class1 in Namespace1.dll, then just rewrite Namespace1.Class1 from scratch, and drop in the Namespace1.dll, and use reflection to intercept other calls, and pass them through the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly override a *virtual* method which you're inheriting from a class in a class library. You do this any time you override `object.ToString()`, for example!

You can't "override a class entirely" though - I don't know what that would even mean. Likewise you can't add a method to an existing class although you can:

- Use extension methods to "pretend" to add another method (but no state, and no properties)
- Derive from the class (assuming it's not sealed) and declare your own extra methods

If you could tell us what you're trying to achieve, it would be easier to advise you on how to proceed.

EDIT: When you need to add more functionality to the original project, just add it to the original project. Is there any reason you wouldn't be able to change that project later?

Comment: you actually can "override a class entirely" with ICorProfiler and lots of headaches. Some stuff can also be overridden with ICorDebug

Comment: @Sam - Are you really suggesting that somebody should run their production application with something attached to the profiling or debugging APIs? You can *always* do something with enough time and effort, but I think it's safe to assume Jon meant you cannot do this in any sane way.

Comment: You can also weave stuff in with a loader using postsharp, that is less painful. some problems call for weaving, for example if you are trying to profile bits of the SqlClient so you get stack traces for your SQL calls. You can also intercept stuff with RealProxy.

Comment: Granted, this stuff is a mine field and not sexy like Ruby alias_method

Comment: i figured it out: 
basic funtionality of the program must be altered at it's base. theres no way round that.

Inherited classes allow you to interchage the child class with another one that implements the same interface.

for me this whole problem arose becasue i was using a sql database and apparently it's nigh impossible to model that in OO code.

Answer (score 0):

> What i'm trying to achieve: i have to
>   create a project now and add it to a
>   larger project as a dll file. but
>   we've been told that we'll need to add
>   more functionality to the original
>   project next month. I'm trying to
>   figure out the best way to go about
>   this. the smaller project is based on
>   mvc design.

The current best practice is to use inversion of control (eg. [ninject](http://ninject.org/)) for these kind of things, if you have a central place for all you dependencies you can wire them up however you like at runtime, intercepting bits and pieces as you wish.