# Overriding method from library

Tags: c#, methods, overriding, virtual

There is a virtual method in a library that my C# project references. How can I override this method in another class within my application?

Example:

```
namespace TheLibary
{
   class SomeClass
   {
      public virtual void TheMethod()
      {
           //Do Stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Then in my project:

```
using theLibary;
namespace TheProject
{
   class SomeClass
   {
       public override <Help>
   }
}
```

**Edit:** Confusion and totally forgetting that this class didn't inherit from the libraries class messed me up, it was late :)

Comment: You can watch : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230219/is-it-possible-to-override-a-method-in-a-class-in-a-dll-file>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should study a bit about OOP (and inheritance in particular) before getting down to any serious coding. For quick reference, here’s an example of how to override a method:

```
namespace TheDll
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public virtual void TheMethod()
        { }
    }
}

namespace TheProject
{
    public class DerivedClass : SomeClass
    {
        public override void TheMethod()
        { }
    }
}
```

You should observe that the signature of the overriding method (including its name) *must* be the same. The derived class, on the other hand, may (and typically should, for clarity) be named differently.

Comment: I understand how to override a method that way, but am wondering if its possible from a diferent dll.

Comment: Yes. In the above example, `DerivedClass` may be defined in a different assembly from `SomeClass`, provided that `SomeClass` is declared as public.

Comment: Well whats weird, is Im using XNA to make my application, It has a method called BeginDraw(GameTime), and my dll im referencing (Neoforce Controls) also has a BeginDraw(gameTime)

Comment: You need to _derive_ from a class in order to override its methods. Could you paste what your class declaration looks like? As in: `public class MyClass : BaseClass`. Does it have a `:` followed by another class name (the base class)?

Comment: my dll looks like  public class Manager : DrawableGameComponent, and my prodject class looks as public class MyGame : Application

Comment: In .NET, you can only override methods if your class derives from the class in which they are defined. What exactly are you trying to achieve by “overriding” the method? You realize that instances of the base `Manager` would still use the original method, and that only instances of your derived `MyGame` class would use the overriding method?

Comment: Uh Sorry, if figured it out. It was a problem in xna, I was calling base.Draw after something else, which made it not draw some things. I thought i had to override a method. Sorry for the confusion. [marked as answer incase anyone else really does need this]

Comment: I got a feeling that overriding methods wasn’t the way to go. Glad you solved your problem anyway.

Comment: Man looking back on some of my old questions and feeling so stupid :P